# TextBox keypress using jquery

Tags: jquery

(I m using html + J-query )
I have a situation in which I have a Text box ,and
whenever the user types anything in it for the first time the character must be appended with @ symbol, and the next characters typed must be placed just before the @ symbol.

for ex.
1st char typed:
c@
2nd char typed:
cf@

This is what I have tried so far,

```
    '<script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){               
       var v=$('#title').val();
         if(!v)
             {
                $('#title').on('key up', function(){
                this.value = this.value+'@';
                });
             }
         else
           var s=this.value;
           var x=s.replace(s. sub string (s.length-1, s.length),'@' );
     });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="title" value=""/>
    </body>`
```

Comment: What i understood from this question you want to append @ at the end ?? or only for 2 letters append then normal tying i.e cf@abc

Comment: append @ at the end but only once when first char is typed.
further characters typed must appear before @

Comment: What if the First character enetered in the textbox is space as i have answered keeping this thing also in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly look into the below code it will serve your purpose:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtDemo" />
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#txtDemo').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 1) {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf('@') === -1) {
            $(this).val($(this).val() + '@');
        }
        else {
            $(this).val('')
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf('@') === -1) {
            $(this).val($(this).val() + '@');
        }
        else {
            var jam = $(this).val().split('@');
            $(this).val(jam[0] + jam[1] + '@')
        }
    }
 })
})
```

Comment: Hey Thanks guys for your reply 
@nitin the code doesnt add @ when i run

Comment: @user3339974 I hope you have changed the ID of your control correctly

Comment: it was the first thing i did

Comment: Hey Sorry @Nitin Rawat your solution is perfect it was my ide issue, but on chrome its running as required.

thank you nitin and all.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I just got it to work

http://jsfiddle.net/DmV8e/

Html

```
<input type="text" id="title" value="" />
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var titleValue = null;                  //Create a variable to store the value
    $('#title').keyup(function () {         //properly bind the keyup function
        if (titleValue == null) {           //check to see if the stored value is null
            this.value = this.value + '@';  //append the @ symbol to the end of the value
            this.setSelectionRange(1, 1);   //basically set the cursor's index to 1
            titleValue = this.value;        //store the new value
        } else if (this.value == "") {      //if the value was not null, check to see if the textbox is empty
            titleValue = null;              //reset the variable to null so the first if will trip on keyup
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I liked your method also but there are some problems that i want to notify: Move the cursor to the last character that is @ and remove it and then it never come back even after adding new characters.

Comment: Second: this.setSelectionRange is not browser compatible . It creates problems with some versions of IE

Comment: updated version that always places the @ at the end (it cannot be removed), but, typing after the @ symbol will throw another on the end...doh http://jsfiddle.net/DmV8e/1/

Comment: there are still many problems: 1> keep giving spaces it will keep adding @. 2> put @ it will add 2 @'s after that.

Comment: zack the code which you posted is adding @ after each input.

Comment: if i place an alert under each if and else only alert under 
$('#title').keyup(function() {
alert("1st");

gets popped.